# Access initialize function's variable in other function

Tags: magento2, javascript, template

I have a JS file where I am getting .phtml variable `dates` like:

```
initialize: function (config)
{
    dates = config.dates;
    this.test();
}

test: function(){
    //get variable dates
}

another: function(){
    //get variable dates
}
```

How to access `dates` without passing in function i.e make `dates` available to all function

Comment: Declare `var dates` outside of the initialize method ? And then you can access it the same way you access the methods with this.dates ?

Comment: If I declare outside, How to access variable ? i.e config.dates

Comment: It's just a scope variable visibility issue : See for the js example there : https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_scope_global